# Divison in Assembly 8086 program

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I have this code in Assembly Language which gets two numbers and display their product.

```
.model small
.stack 50h 

.data
Prompt1 db 'Enter the first number: ', 13d, 10d, '$'
Prompt2 db 'Enter the second number: ', 13d, 10d, '$'
Result  db 'The multiplication result is : ', 13d, 10d, '$'

.code
main_method Proc
    Mov Ax, @Data
    Mov Ds, Ax

    ;---------------

    Mov Dx, Offset Prompt1
    Mov Ah, 09
    int 21h

    Mov Ah, 01
    int 21h
    Mov Bl, Al
    Sub Bl, 48


    Mov Dx, Offset Prompt2
    Mov Ah, 09
    int 21h
    Mov Ah, 01
    int 21h
    Sub Al, 48

    Mov Dx, Offset Result
    Mov Ah, 09
    int 21h

    Mul Bl
    Add Al, 48
    Mov Dl, Al
    Mov Ah, 02
    int 21h

    Mov Ah, 4ch
    int 21h

main_method endp 
end main_method
```

Now, how do I convert this program into one which gets two numbers and show their division results i.e. remainder(in Ah register) and quotient (in Al register)?
Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? the `mul` is standing out there, just waiting to be replaced...

Comment: What's The Deal With The Awkward/Unusual Capitalisation?

Comment: This "Unusual Capitalization" looks fine :)